# How do I solve a partial fractions question when $x$ can’t equal any solutions?

Tags: partial-fractions

[image: Image of the question]

How do I solve $A(i)$ and $A(ii)$ when $x$ can't equal $-2/5$ or $1/2$? The only method I’m aware of for partial fractions requires these values to be subbed in and I’m confused. Sorry if the image is obstructed by my scruffy writing.
If it’s helpful, part $b$ involves binomial expansion.

Comment: Have you studied the [cover up method](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes03/h.pdf)?

Comment: These values are excluded, for obvious reasons, from the domain of the function $f(x)$ but are perfectly valid and applicable in the polynomial identity you have written down for the purposes of calculating the unknown constants